# How to stable reverse sort a slice in Go?

Tags: sorting, go, reverse, stability

I do have

```
4, 5', 6, 5''
```

and want to reverse stable sort as

```
6, 5', 5'', 4
```

but not

```
6, 5'', 5', 4
```

This (invalid) code would not work

```
keys := []int{4, 5', 6, 5''}
sort.Stable(sort.Reverse(sort.Ints(keys)))
```

it would produce:

```
6, 5'', 5', 4
```

---

Here the problem is shown as simplified as a slice of integers, but In reality I need to use it applied to a slice of structs

```
type myStruct struct {
    t time.Time
    d time.Duration
}
```

and reverse stable sort based in the `t` field.

---

Edit: After few comments I made explicit that the integer one is a non working example to simplify the problem.

Comment: Your code not working: https://play.golang.org/p/A3a5FPZL8Q

Comment: @Aminadav of course, it's a simplified example using integers, to represent  the general problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `sort.Interface` interface on your custom struct.

```
type myStruct struct{
    t time.Time
    d time.Duration
}

type Slice []myStruct

func (s Slice) Len() int {  return len(s) }

func (s Slice) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return (s[i].t).After(s[j].t)
}

func (s Slice) Swap(i, j int) {
    s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}
```

In your case, following function will sort in reverse order based on `t`

```
func (s Slice) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return (s[i].t).After(s[j].t)
}
```

`(s[i].t).After(s[j].t)` reports whether `s[i].t` is after `s[j].t`.

If you want only sort, use following one

```
func (s Slice) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return (s[i].t).Before(s[j].t)
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes definitely this helps. It's actually the same solution as Elwinar, shown here. This should to the job

Comment: Yes...  Same as Elwinar. I've just added implementation for your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Implement the `sort.Interface` interface on a slice type, so you can choose the sort order, and apply a stable sort on it. Example : https://play.golang.org/p/TWAtH7asi3

Comment: I looked at that however the behaviour I am looking for is not the same as 'reverse and stable sort'. I want the ordering of equal element to be applied as in the original list, and not as in the reversed one.

Comment: Well, unless I'm mistaken about your example, the code I provided works and would produce your first example.

Comment: HA! I see what you did. You implemented Less() as '>'. That's smart.

Comment: @LorenzoBelli: Elwinar did _not_ suppose to reverse after stable sorting: He proposed to stable sort with `Less` checking for more. His answer is correct.

Comment: You can still use `sort.Reverse` with a normal definition of `Less`. Did you try it? See https://play.golang.org/p/s8FezweFOj.

Comment: True that. The implementation of `sort.Reverse` is simply a type that implements `sort.Interface`, and reverse the results to `Less`. In fact, it should work too. 

That being said, depending on if your "reverse sort" is supposed to be the normal way to sort your values, I would advise to implement the interface using whatever definition of "i should be before j" and don't worry about the "integer sorting": if you're sorting scores for example, you'll want the biggest first.

Comment: @AndySchweig That is very very useful. That is not what I would have expected: `sort.Stable(sort.Reverse(w))` does not behave the same as reversing and stable sorting!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need to go through the trouble of implementing the sort interface. You can just sort bare using [sort.Slice](https://godoc.org/sort#Slice) or [sort.SliceStable](https://godoc.org/sort#SliceStable).

Here is what worked for me ([go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/P_twYm1Cqg)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    layout := "Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006"
    t1, _ := time.Parse(layout, "Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2008")
    t2, _ := time.Parse(layout, "Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2001")
    t3, _ := time.Parse(layout, "Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2003")
    t4, _ := time.Parse(layout, "Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006")

    timestamps := []struct {
        T time.Time
        d time.Duration
    }{
        {t1, 1},
        {t2, 1},
        {t3, 1},
        {t4, 1},
    }

    // forward
    sort.Slice(timestamps, func(i, j int) bool { 
        return timestamps[i].T.Before(timestamps[j].T) 
    })
    fmt.Println("By time:", timestamps)

    // reverse
    sort.Slice(timestamps, func(i, j int) bool { 
        return timestamps[i].T.After(timestamps[j].T) 
    })
    fmt.Println("By time:", timestamps)
}
```